# Compare the same column values in a table and then the take their relationship value from other table

Tags: sql, join

I have a table like below:

```
ID  Role  CompanyID
1   T     123
2   S     1234
3   B     12345
```

T's company id has relationship with S's and B's company ids.The value of their relationship is in another table like below:

```
Rel      CompanyId1    CompanyId
Private  1234          123
Public   12345         123
```

Of course first I have to join the two tables and then I have to get the relationship of T(123) with S(1234) and B(12345) from the table 2 and on the basis of that I have to create another column which will be if the relationship of T with S and B is private then 1 and if public then 0

It should be like this

```
Id     Role   Companyid   BoolCol
1      T      123         for T there is no need to fill this col can be null
2      S      1234        1 becoz rel b/w T and S is private
3      B      12345       0 becoz rel b/w T and B is public
```

The relationship is only of T with another companies not the other way around

Any help will be appreciated.......

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code:

```
select id, role,a.companyid,rel,case when rel='Private' then 1 when rel='Public' then 0 else null end as boolcol
from first_table a left join relation_table b
on a.companid=b.companyid1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can join the table using **Left join** on CompanyId in first table and CompanyId1 in second table and use **case when** statement to get the BoolCol column.

```
select a.*,case when b.rel = 'Private' then 1
                when b.rel = 'Public' then 0   
                else NULL 
                end as BoolCol
from table1 a
left join
table2 b
on a.companyid = b.companyid1;
```

Let me know in case you of any queries.

Comment: Reason for DV please?